# Python input only accept one argument

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am writing a text game in python 3.3.4, at one point I ask for a name. Is there a a way to only accept one name, (one argument to the input) and if the user inputs more than one arg.
Here is what I currently have.

```
name =input('Piggy: What is your name?\n').title()
time.sleep(1)
print('Hello, {}. Piggy is what they call me.'.format(name))
time.sleep(1)
print('{}: Nice to meet you'.format(name))
time.sleep(1)
print('** Objective Two Completed **')
```

I am guessing I will need to use something like while, and then if and elif.
Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `input()` only accepts one string.

Comment: "and if the user inputs more than one arg" ... what?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, for ex. if someone inputs their name as dawson diaz, whereas I only would like their first name

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I would like only a first name.

Comment: Instead of “What is your name?” you could ask “How should I call you?”

Comment: "Mary Jo" is a first name.

Comment: @poke What if someone responds with "none of your business" and then the program returns "Hello, none of your business"

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I suppose you are right,

Comment: @dawsondiaz Then that’s their own fault :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while True:
    name = input("What is your name? ").strip()
    if len(name.split()) == 1:
        name = name.title()
        break
    else:
        print("Too long! Make it shorter!")

enter code here
```